# Check FK Constraints after BULK INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a couple of big datasets ( ~O(1TB) ), which I want to to import into my database. I use `BULK INSERT` to import data into temporary tables, then use `SELECT` and `INSERT INTO` to fill my real tables with the data. This is because I want to change the order of some things, and split some data files into logical tables. And if this functionality is not needed, I just `BULK INSERT` directly into my target table.

I would like to check if all foreign key constraints have been enforced. If I flag `BULK INSERT` to `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` during the import stage the import process slows down to a crawl.

Is there a command to do this after the fact? I have *very limited* familiarity with SQL Server, and databasing in general.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Suggested reading : [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189496.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check one table:

```
alter table YourTable with check check constraint all
```

To check all tables:

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'alter table ? with check check constraint all'
```

Comment: Hm, I tried 'alter table MyTable with check check constraint all' and got a... "Command(s) completed successfully." would it have failed otherwise?

Comment: Yes. You'd get an error like "ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with COLUMN FOREIGN KEY constraint ..." if there was a violation.

Answer (score 2):

How many tables/foreign keys are you looking at?  Have you considering writing a quick custom query that checks for orphaned rows?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing right now. There are roughly 10 tables some of which cross-reference each other. I thought that there could be a way to save some time. :)

Comment: I like this answer +1, you need to know where the FK's not valid

Answer (score 1):

Tibor Karaszi wrote a great article about trusted constraints: [Non-trusted constraints](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2008/01/12/non-trusted-constraints.aspx)

Comment: Found a "DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS()" hint in that post, going to try it out. :)