# Can bulkinsert cause zombie records?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm uploading a large set of data from an XML file to DB using Sql Server Bulkinsert, through a scheduled job running silently at night.

**Background**

Consider this dummy model:

```
+====================+       +====================+
+  INVOICE           +       +  INVOICE LINES     +
+====================+       +====================+
+ PK + InvoiceId     +-I-┐   + PK + InvoiceLineId +
+    + ...           +   └IX-+ FK + InvoiceId     +
+    + ...           +       +    + ...           +
+====================+       +====================+
```

My source is expected to provide me with reliable data, but mistakes/errors do happen. The `InvoiceId` FK in `Invoice Lines` could potentially point to an `InvoiceId` that does not exist in table `Invoice`.

**My question**

> Can feeding incorrectly referenced data to Bulkinsert cause zombie records?

Would inserting them cause (loggable) warnings once the constraints are turned on again?

If so, these would be human detectable. I could create a post-upload cleanup. Pre-upload checks would be very complex and as said, are not my responsibility.

**PS**

To be extra clear on what I mean with Zombie records:

> Records stored in database that have no reason to exist because they
>   have a reference towards a dependency, through a foreign key, 
>   in another table that is non-existant.

As far as I'm aware that is a generally accepted term.

Comment: what are Zombie records ?

Comment: Easiest thing to do is run an audit report using NOT EXISTS to find these beforehand. Re enabling FK constraints won't give you a list of broken constraints but a simple SELECT will. What will you do with these bad records? forward to a human to check or delete?

Comment: When you turn back the constraints ,the constraints will fail.

Comment: If you do the bulk insert with [`CHECK_CONSTRAINTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188365), then no. Otherwise, then yes, and the constraint will be marked as "not trusted" regardless of whether you actually violate integrity. You can [check them afterwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588052/check-fk-constraints-after-bulk-insert), though this will take some time on very large tables (possibly more than just bulk inserting with constraints).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I'm inclined to prefer automatic corrections, such as a DB job or a post-process that cleans up after the upload.

Comment: I think `orphan records` is a better term.

Comment: I prefer automatic corrections too but how do you automatically generate a header record if the data doesn't exist? It's not possible.

Comment: @mxmissile: I think there's a difference, zombies are abominations to nature (the model) that should never have existed, orphans did have meaning at some point, zombies never do/did.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I would just delete all zombie records. They have no meaning and you indeed can't _invent_ meaning for them.

Comment: But if there is a value on the line item you're now deleting values. If you have a line without a header you basically have corrupt data

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: It would be corrupt the moment I receive it. I would _purge_all those records and ask my source to check and resend.

Comment: There's the human intervention bit. But it's all hypothetical really!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can cause `INVOICE LINES` rows referencing non-existing  `INVOICE` ("zombie records" as you put it), if `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` option is not specified

> CHECK_CONSTRAINTS Specifies that all constraints on the target table
>   or view must be checked during the bulk-import operation. Without the
>   CHECK_CONSTRAINTS option, any CHECK and FOREIGN KEY constraints are
>   ignored, and after the operation, the constraint on the table is
>   marked as not-trusted.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

You can detect bad rows with a post-load query

```
SELECT * 
FROM [INVOICE LINES] il
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM INVOICE i WHERE i.InvoiceId =il.InvoiceId ) ;
```